# Links are causing text to move up in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5boilerplate

Here is the cuplrit: http://www.franzsarmiento.com/contact_information.jsp

I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate and for some reason in Opera, when I hover above the links, the text moves up. I don't have any a:hover CSS for those links. This issue only happens in Opera, I checked all other browsers. I tested this on Opera 11 and 12.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Opera 12.00

Comment: @elclanrs when you hover a link by the first time, the body text moves up by ~2 pixels.

Comment: Yes Fabricio that's exactly what my issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be coming from the `a:hover, a:active { outline: 0 }` on line 19 of the css.  The page has a 3px outline on page load then on hover becomes 0px.  You can remove the a:hover from that rule or add the same rule to the anchor tags `a { outline: 0 }`, or change it to whatever behaviour you want to happen on :hover and :active.

Comment: But that line of code comes from HTML5 Boilerplate. Wont it break some other stuff?

Comment: Depending on which you choose, it will change the behaviour of outlines on your page. After looking at your site a bit more, the issue could also be coming from your CSS code `#main-wrapper{overflow:auto}`, is there a reason why you're using this rule here?